# How to redirect one url to another url using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect old url to new url but it is not redirecting.

Old url: http://domain.com/STACK/App/
New url: http://domain.com/stack-app

And my .htaccess file 
Redirect  301 /STACK/App http://domain.com/stack-app

Thanks,

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  http://domain.com/STACK/App/ /http://domain.com/stack-app [R=301,L]
```

For more help go to this link:--
http://edward-designer.com/web/htaccess-url-rewrite-simplified/

Comment: Hi manish,thanks for your reply I have tried this but its not working. I am getting file not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your very first redirect rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/STACK/App/?$ /stack-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the mod_rewrite section of your .htaccess file, add the following lines on the old site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\STACK\App\$
   RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.com/stack-app/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to redirect your website using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

for non www version, you can use the following,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```